# CASE Statement Issue Date

Tags: mysql, case, case-statement

This is my table structure.

```
===============================================
main_section | date_of_pay | currency | amount
===============================================

Tender         20-02-2016    INR        2000
Tender         20-02-2016    INR        1500
Tender         20-02-2016    INR        1850
PBG            20-02-2016    INR        1850
SD             20-02-2016    INR        1850
===============================================
```

Iam trying to do a CASE statement in which if 'main_section=Tender' it should return the tender amount,currencyand date_of_pay. if its PBG it should return the PBG amount,currency and date_of_pay. and simultaneously for SD. If there are more than one record, then it should sum and return the amount ( Here Tender has more than one record). Can anyone help me with this. The following is the case statement which i tried. Its working properly, but not displaying the date_of_pay, its showing empty (NULL).

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Tender' THEN com_payments.amount END) AS tendamount,
SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'SD' THEN com_payments.amount END) AS banksdamount,  
SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'PBG' THEN com_payments.amount END) AS bankpbgamount,     

MAX(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Tender Fee' THEN com_payments.amt_curr END) AS tendcurrency,
MAX(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank Guarantee SD' THEN com_payments.amt_curr END) AS banksdcurrency,
MAX(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank Guarantee PBG' THEN com_payments.amt_curr END) AS bankpbgcurrency,

CASE WHEN main_section = 'Tender Fee' THEN com_payments.date_of_pay END AS tendbankdop,
CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank Guarantee SD' THEN com_payments.date_of_pay END AS banksdbankdop,
CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank Guarantee PBG' THEN com_payments.date_of_pay END AS bankpbgbankdop

FROM TABLE
```

May be iam making a mistake.iam not sure. Anyone to help me?

Comment: add `(CASE WHEN ... END)` to last three `case when`

Comment: you need all output in single row....

Comment: Yes that's what iam looking at, in a single row

Comment: How about MAX again?

Comment: Yes i solved it by adding MAX.